# Maximal contiguous subarray with at most K elements

Tags: python, time-complexity, max, sub-array, contiguous

Is there a way to find in O(N) complexity, a maximal contiguous subarray **with at most K elements**.

Or there isn't such a possibility.

for example:

A = [4, -2, 6, 4, -2, 6]

K = 3

because 6 and 4 in the middle are equal to 10, the function should return 10.

P.S. with O(N*K) it's easy, the question is whether it is possible in O(N)
Here is an algorithm that solves in O(N*K) time:

```py
def maxContiguousFragment(arr):
    b = max(arr)
    s = 0
    for i in arr:
        s = max(s + i, i)
        b = max(s, b)
    return b

def max_K_Subarray(arr,k):
    return max(maxContiguousFragment(
            arr[i:i+k] for i in range(len(arr)-k)))
```

Comment: add your code which you try till now.

Comment: Yes it answers the question thank you